# image as hyperlink in python / Tkinter

Tags: python, hyperlink, tkinter, wiki

I guess the answer is no, but I have to ask...
I wrote a wiki in python/tkinter, where the hyperlinks are managed by tkHyperlinkManager (http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm) in a text widget.
All is perfect, but I'd like also to use clickable images - is it possible? I see that hyperlinks work by tags, and I cannot find a way to add tags to an image

alessandro

Comment: I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to create clickable images since `Text` widgets can contain `Tkinter.PhotoImage` instances...

Comment: After looking around a little more, I think you might be right -- One workaround could be to put your image in a label, "insert" the label using `window_create`, and then bind your callbacks to the label.  (You could probably hack that all into tkHyperlinkManager testing whether you recieved a `PhotoImage` or text )...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tkHyperLinkManager doesn't support it, but it's very simple with the features already built in to the text widget. All you need to do is create a label with your image, embed the label, and add a binding to the label.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
...
image_link = tk.Label(text_widget, image=my_image, cursor="left_ptr")
image_link.bind("<1>", do_something)
text_widget.window_create("insert", window=image_link)
```